# How to show that $\int \|y-y_0\|\nu(dy)<\infty? $

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a uniformly random variable on $[0,1]$.  Since $Y$ is supported on $[\cos(2),1]$, then we can define a probability measure on $R$ so that $Y\sim \nu$.

How to show that for any $y_0\in R$ we have
$$
\int \|y-y_0\|\nu(dy)<\infty?
$$

Comment: When the integrand is bounded and the measure is finite, the integral is finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the definitions you have that

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} |y-y_0|\nu(dy)=\int_{\Omega }|Y-y_0|\,d P\leqslant \int_{\Omega }(|Y|+|y_0|)\,d P\leqslant 1+|y_0|\tag1
$$

as $|Y|\leqslant 1$. For a more elementary approach note that

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}|y-y_0|\nu (dy)\leqslant \int_{\mathbb{R}}|y|\nu (dy)+\int_{\mathbb{R}}|y_0|\nu (dy)\tag2
$$

where I used the triangle inequality and the linearity of the integral. Now, the first integral in the RHS of (2) is just the expected value of $|Y|$, what is finite because $|Y|\leqslant 1$ so

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}|y|\nu (dy)\leqslant \int_{[-1,1]}\nu (dy)=\Pr [|Y|\leqslant 1]=1\tag3
$$

Now the second integral in the RHS of (2) is just $|y_0|$ by the linearity of the integral, so again we reach the same bound as in (1).

Comment: What is your $\Omega$ here?

Comment: it is the underlying probability space, the space of events. Remember that a random variable is a function $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. I will add a more elementary approach

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4500945/is-the-coupling-of-two-probability-distribution-pi-in-mathcalp0-1-times? Thank you!